# Insert new row in gridview by specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, web-applications, devexpress

I'm using Devexpress tool  anyone please help me?

I'm using Devexpress tool to develop my website. But i have some problems so i hope anyone could help me. I really need it in my project. Please see here:

http://www.fiditour.com/dattourtructuyen.aspx?id=731

look section above capcha. I have 2 questions:
- How they can add textbox in gridview?
- How they can add new row by value in textbox?

Thank for reading!

Comment: I think it will be great if you mention what area you are having problems with rather than posting link to other sites !!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty http://i.stack.imgur.com/eHTQA.jpg

You see textbox, when you enter a new value (example: 2)...See gridview below, new row will be added. What's should i do?

Answer (score 0):

That is not textboxes in the grid. They are editable cells.

You can access the values entered by using the handler of the first row, then like @Давид Дача Милинкови mentionned, you add the specified row.

Answer (score 0):

So as to have a textbox inside the column you must insert a `GridViewDataTextColumn` not just a `GridViewDataColumn`.

In the `CellEditorInitialize` event of the Grid you can pass the Default Value to `e.Editor`.